# Why bson_iter_type is 0x27,0x17?

Tags: bson

I used the bson_iter_type() to get the type of iter. But the results (0x27, 0x17,0x1a,0x1b) are not listed in the official document [mongodb-api-document](https://api.mongodb.org/libbson/current/bson_iter_type.html). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bson_iter_init (&iter, my_bson_doc), iter does not point at the first element, but something ahead of the first element. After bson_iter_init (&iter, my_bson_doc) and  bson_iter_next (&iter), iter will point at the first element if there are at least one element in bson. So, my problem stems from that the return of bson_iter_type() is not the type of the first element, but other things. 
Now, bson_iter_next (&iter) is called to make sure iter point at the first element before bson_iter_type(). My problem is solved.